# What is the best way for authenticating and authorizing Web Api for multiple consumers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have a large asp.net mvc website that we are planning to break down into multiple micro sites.

we also have an api which is used by external customers.

we would like to authenticate the requests from our websites and the api consumers of our web api.

ideally we would like to do this without having to make major changes in the authentication mechanism.

since the site is being broken into multiple asp.net mvc solutions would we be able to use the same asp.net forms authentication on our web api layer or do we have to use authentication tokens?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using JWT tokens where it will simplify this, you can read my detailed [post here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/)

Answer (score 1):

I would create an authentication server. I would also move toward token-base authentication.

Check this out http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: Or you can check out [Thinktecture IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/)